# How to convert wordpress plugin to simple php script

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to run a wordpress plugin in my localhost without using wordpress. How to convert wp plugin to simple php script?

Comment: To accomplish the same, you should have sound knowledge of WordPress only then you could convert the WordPress plugin code into simple PHP script.

Answer (score 0):

First o all look in [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org) and search here for every function that appears in your plugin. If a function from your plugin appears in codex, try to reimplement it. Remove all add_action, do_action, add_filter and all Wordpress stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I would just start the main PHP file and start solving each occurring error.

For a start, you can add some [initial constants](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_initial_constants/) and the `get_option()` function:

```
define( 'MINUTE_IN_SECONDS', 60);
define( 'WP_DEBUG', false);

function get_option( $option, $default = false ) {
    pre='PLUGINNAME_DEFAULT'
    $option = trim( $option );
    if ( empty( $option ) ) return false;
    return constant(strtoupper($pre"_".$option);
}
```

try to solve every occurring problem by enabling php error notices and search for each missing wordpress function occurring in the errors